# Python: How can I iterate within columns to make the difference the value and its previous one?

Tags: python, pandas

I am going mad with this code.
I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
Business Date   dic-22  gen-23  feb-23
03/10/2022   112,0   121,1   131,2 
04/10/2022   87,0    103,0   122,5 
05/10/2022   114,3   102,8   99,6 
06/10/2022   101,7   116,6   104,3 
07/10/2022   116,6   103,7   110,8 
10/10/2022   108,8   107,3   112,0
```

I want to make the division for each value and its previous one, per column.
So like: 87/112; 114/87;... for each column
In order to have

```
Business Date   dic-22  gen-23  feb-23
03/10/2022  0   0   0
04/10/2022   0,8     0,9     0,9   
05/10/2022   1,3     1,0     0,8   
06/10/2022   0,9     1,1     1,0   
07/10/2022   1,1     0,9     1,1   
10/10/2022   0,9     1,0     1,0
```

Then, I would like to get the natural logarithm of these numbers.

I have tried to to it but I'm stuck with the first part (the division within values).

The code does not work.
Offering virtual mojitos to anyone willing to help.

```
for i, column in df.items():
    for j, row in df.iterrows():
       # if j > 0:  # Skip first row
            df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:] / df.iloc[:, 1:].shift()`
```

Comment: what is the meaning of the second number liske 0, 8 . what is the meaning of 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) after temporarily setting your dates as index:

```
tmp = df.set_index('Business Date')
out = (tmp/tmp.shift()).reset_index()
```

*NB. in python the decimal separator is `.`, not `,`, make sure to use the correct format. Or convert from strings using `tmp = df.set_index('Business Date').apply(lambda s: pd.to_numeric(s.str.replace(',', '.')))`.*

Output:

```
  Business Date    dic-22    gen-23    feb-23
0    03/10/2022       NaN       NaN       NaN
1    04/10/2022  0.776786  0.850537  0.933689
2    05/10/2022  1.313793  0.998058  0.813061
3    06/10/2022  0.889764  1.134241  1.047189
4    07/10/2022  1.146509  0.889365  1.062320
5    10/10/2022  0.933105  1.034716  1.010830
```

If you want to fill with NaNs with zeros and round:

```
out = (tmp/tmp.shift()).fillna(0).round(1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Business Date  dic-22  gen-23  feb-23
0    03/10/2022     0.0     0.0     0.0
1    04/10/2022     0.8     0.9     0.9
2    05/10/2022     1.3     1.0     0.8
3    06/10/2022     0.9     1.1     1.0
4    07/10/2022     1.1     0.9     1.1
5    10/10/2022     0.9     1.0     1.0
```

##### handling non consecutive dates differently

For the sake of generalization, as your dates are not consecutive. In your example you shift to the previous available date. If instead, you wanted to access the exact previous day (10/10/2022 -> 09/10/2022), then you would need to change the code to:

```
df['Business Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Business Date'], dayfirst=True)

tmp = df.set_index('Business Date')
out = (tmp/tmp.shift(freq='1D')).fillna(0).round(1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Business Date  dic-22  gen-23  feb-23
0    2022-10-03     0.0     0.0     0.0
1    2022-10-04     0.8     0.9     0.9
2    2022-10-05     1.3     1.0     0.8
3    2022-10-06     0.9     1.1     1.0
4    2022-10-07     1.1     0.9     1.1
5    2022-10-08     0.0     0.0     0.0
6    2022-10-10     0.0     0.0     0.0
7    2022-10-11     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: it says ""None of ['Business Date'] are in the columns""...

Comment: @Medea00 check you example, it should be there ;) What is the output of `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: Ahh, Maybe I get it. It gets the first column as index, maybe? The dict shows something like: {Timestamp('2022-01-31 00:00:00'): {Timestamp('2022-01-03 00:00:00'): 80.78192999999999, Timestamp('2022-01-04 00:00:00'): 90.32244, Timestamp('2022-01-05 00:00:00'): 82.85291000000001, Timestamp('2022-01-06 00:00:00'): 82.98248999999998, Timestamp('2022-01-07 00:00:00'): 76.88569999999999, Timestamp('2022-01-10 00:00:00'): 69.64829999999998, Timestamp('2022-01-11

Comment: Yes, likely, then just skip the `set_index`/`reset_index` ;)